# Why does fs.writeFileSync() throws "is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, function, file, fs

I am trying to save some data in a file using fs.writeFileSync, but it doesn't work and I cannot figure out why. It throws the following error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.writeFileSync is not a function`

In my app I use it like this :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const stateFile = "./usersStateFile";

const saveLastEventSequenceId = (sequenceId) => {
    try {
            fs.writeFileSync(stateFile, sequenceId);
        } catch (err) {
          throw err;
        }
     };
```

The `sequenceId` is a number and the `./usersStateFile` doesn't exist, but `fs.writeFileSync()` should create it if it doesn't exist.

What might be the problem ?

Comment: Did you `require`/`import` the `fs` module? If so, please add the import statement to the code snippet.

Comment: is this javascript you wrote supposed to run on a browser? if yes then I dont think it will work

Comment: Do you run the code in nodejs or do you use some packing tool such us webpack or rollup? Or do you run this in browser? Because browser does not have require nor access to fs. You can try do `console.log(fs)` and post the output.

Comment: I run it in my browser with yarn run dev. Then how should I do this to make it work ?

Comment: This will never, ever run in a browser.

Comment: I have a "server" file in my app, but if I write the code there it doesn't work, i mean it doesn't console.log things if I put console.log there

Answer (score 3):

Import `fs` module like so:

```js
const fs = require('fs'); // or `import * as fs from 'fs'` if you're using ES2015+
const stateFile = "./usersStateFile";

const saveLastEventSequenceId = (sequenceId) => {
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(stateFile, sequenceId);
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

You were calling `fs.writeFileSync()` without having a variable named `fs` that's defined in your scope. In this case, `fs` evaluates to `undefined`, which caused the error when trying to invoke its in-existent function member.

Comment: I did defined fs like this but I still get the error

Comment: @RobertBogos are you using NodeJS?

Comment: I am running this in the browser with yarn run dev

Comment: @RobertBogos The fs module is not available in the browser.  This is specific to node and will only work in node.  The browser, for security reasons, has very limited access to your file system... otherwise you could visit any random website and they could read and write to all the files on your computer, including your private key files, passwords, etc.